# JavaFX start method everytime included tabcontent is called

Tags: tabs, javafx-8, fxml, subcontroller

How can I start a method every time a tab is called? I have a `Main.fxml` with a `tabpane` and two `tabs`, I've included a separate fxml for each tab (`tab1.fxml`, `tab2.fxml`).

Main.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>    
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="434.0" prefWidth="428.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.MainController">
   <children>
  <TabPane prefHeight="434.0" prefWidth="428.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
    <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="tab1" text="Tab 1">
           <content>
              <fx:include source="tab1.fxml" />
           </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="tab2" onSelectionChanged="#addView" text="Tab 2">
           <content>
              <fx:include source="tab2.fxml" />
           </content>
      </Tab>
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

MainController.java

```
public class MainController implements Initializable{

    @FXML private Tab tab1;
    @FXML private Tab tab2;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {

    }


    @FXML public void addView(){

    }
}
```

Each FXML has a `Label` which should show how often the tab(content) was called. So if I click on tab ("tab2") the counter label should show "1" and increment by +1 every time I call this tab again. This should happen by using a method within the tab controllers.

tab1.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="249.0" prefWidth="257.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.tab1Controller">
   <children>
     <Label fx:id="lbl_1" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="53.0" text="not clicked" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

tab1Controller.java

```
public class tab1Controller implements Initializable{


     @FXML public  Label lbl_1;

     private static int counter=0;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {


    }

    public void addViewCounter(){
        lbl_1.setText(""+counter);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Tab2.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="249.0" prefWidth="257.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.tab2Controller">
   <children>
     <Label fx:id="lbl_2" layoutX="92.0" layoutY="53.0" text="not clicked" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

tab2Controller.java

```
public class tab1Controller implements Initializable{


     @FXML public  Label lbl_2;

     private static int counter=0;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {


    }

    public void addViewCounter(){
        lbl_2.setText(""+counter);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

I've already tried to solve this problem by using static methods and labels but i get `NullPointerExceptions`, seems like this doesn't work anymore with java 8.
Also I've tried to get the controller by using a `FXMLloader` ... this way I also get a `NullPointerExceptions`.

Isn't there an `onCall` method for the included fmxl or the anchorpane? Or maybe something that makes the controller initialize again.

Any other solutions or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your `counter`s should not be `static`. They belong to the controller *instances*, not the controller class.

You need three things:

1. A reference to the tabPane in the main controller
2. A reference to each of the tab controllers in the main controller.
3. A listener on the tabPane's selected tab, so that you can call a method when the selected tab changes

For the first, just do:

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="434.0" ... >
```

in Main.fxml, and

```
@FXML private TabPane tabPane ;
```

in MainController.java.

For the second, you can use the ["Nested Controller" technique](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers).

You need to add an `fx:id` attribute to each of the `fx:include`s, and then just add references for the controllers in MainController.java. The rule is that if your `fx:include` has  `fx:id="x"`, then the controller from the corresponding FXML file can be injected into a variable with name `xController`. Here I have changed the class names for the controllers to `Tab1Controller` and `Tab2Controller` to follow the standard conventions (and avoid confusion).

In Main.fxml, change the `fx:include`s to include an `fx:id`:

```
<fx:include fx:id="tab1Content" source="tab1.fxml" />

<fx:include fx:id="tab2Content" source="tab2.fxml" />
```

In MainController.java:

```
@FXML private Tab1Controller tab1ContentController ;
@FXML private Tab2Controller tab2ContentController ;
```

Now in `MainController`'s `initialize()` method just set up the listener:

```
public void initialize() {
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
        .addListener((obs, oldTab, newTab) -> {
            if (newTab == tab1) {
                tab1ContentController.addViewCounter();
            } else if (newTab == tab2) {
                tab2ContentController.addViewCounter();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I've already tried this approach, but i missed to add the "Controller" after the fx:id-name, so i did get error messages all the time.